# TypeScript: express function return type as the relationship between two unions

Tags: typescript

I have two unions, A and B, that share a common identifier, `key`.

A is the input to the function, `foo`, and B is the result of the function `foo`.

`foo` is guaranteed to pick an item from the B union that has the same `key`
as the given A.

I want to express that fact in the return type of `foo`.

This code might better show what I mean:

```js
type UnionA =
  | {
      key: "one";
    }
  | {
      key: "two";
    };

type UnionB =
  | {
      key: "one";
      value: boolean;
    }
  | {
      key: "two";
      value: string;
    };

const b: UnionB[] = [
  { key: "two", value: "ok" },
  { key: "one", value: true },
];

function foo(val: UnionA): UnionB | undefined {
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (val.key === b[i].key) {
      return b[i];
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}

const c = foo({ key: "two" });

// The below produces an error:
// Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | boolean'
//
// But it's actually guaranteed to be a string
console.log(c && c.value.length);
```

Is it possible to tell TypeScript that the return type of `foo` depends on the value of 
the `key` property in the input parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a function `UnionA -> UnionB` and both unions share a common `key` property to express their relation, we can make the input generic and [extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) output with `Extract<UnionB, { key: T["key"] }>`:

```
function foo<T extends UnionA>(val: T): Extract<UnionB, { key: T["key"] }> | undefined {
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (val.key === b[i].key) {
            return b[i] as Extract<UnionB, { key: T["key"] }>; // unresolved generic, cast
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

const c = foo({ key: "two" }); // { key: "two"; value: string; } | undefined
console.log(c && c.value); // "ok"
```

[Full example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=35&pln=33&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwIJQLwFgBQV9QA%20UA3rgRVANYQgBcUARChIwNzkEC%20n%20xZeSvhr0mwAO5J2vKFw45coSLEQoAQphn8ZFEQ2ZxW8ofgBuAQwA2AVwgMARkiSWI5uMe5bSOgnrGTpQSELGzsoAGdgACcEOABzD3w5XFwAYxRIqHtMKABtGRJqWn0JKQAaKBDbfSQqRlkygqLRA1YKqrDo2wbcAF0oc3CodLhI%20VwAM2s4VOBkOCgJpwAeABUoCAAPYAg4ABMh%20HnUAD4AChCGVYBKBgBRbajzWeWj9QrCv1XcxhFGfq4JyIUGmewgE1iED23iCiyQUSgZxcwCgCByAAY2KioMssgA6FzxYAACyxCAA1OTrjCTKiJoiQniRJgMBgsrkEL0mbRqQJaRQohBgNYogt7Bz%20oMoA9os9gK9VHA1B9mlcfn8AScsQB6bUguCC8LOUxQqBxXYQGKpCqpQbAHxJGQ8WGC4Wi-VgiGGPbyZ1pDIo1I5JZIM6fYr%20KSya46vXhlqldiVKzVCLRWIJWTA0HgyF7f2jZwQAlIOJnIMAMgrwzxHRjUF1TFqjCAA)

Answer (score 1):

I have another possible solution that might work for your use case, but does not exactly answer your question. You can reverse the problem and create `UnionA` from `UnionB` like that

```
type UnionB = {
      key: "one";
      value: boolean;
    }
  | {
      key: "two";
      value: string;
};
type Key = UnionB["key"]
type UnionA = Record<"key", Key>
```

Here is a working [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwEJQLxQN4CgoGEDWEIAXFAEQoSUDc+hBAbgIYA2ArhBQEZJJ2EVnAZMAvowA+ORkxLkqwAO5J6cwmy48oAZ2AAnBHADmDcQ1CQoAaVKZYiFKgDalBZQC6uK9HjI4AEEHACUIAGMkAwATAB53UkoAGltSAD5cXEi4fSheCn9nF08HF0ZsKAUKShU1FK1uaqQiSihxJPLK0ia4WnqORqhDbjaOzwZcADNOOHDgAKhJgQAKLQKnIIBKdYD0GRnoiEnjCGjZAiWDKGWhYCgEBwAGOnuoWLyAOiFTYAALF4QAGpAZtzoQEJNrloPgpMBgsLwXAhPDDSKC8EwCAYIMBOAY4HkkeMNJICJJGNjcfioAcjidouZMtlcuEHEskMsKlUlKpWuJNnQgA)